# MySQLI Fatal Error in production but not development

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database');

$insert = "INSERT INTO submissions ( client_name, client_company ) VALUES ('$client_name', '$client_company' )";

if ( $mysqli->query($insert) === TRUE ) {
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $mysqli . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}
```

In my development environment it runs perfectly, inserting the variables into the correct table columns.

However in production I get this error:

> Catchable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli could not be converted
>   to string in  'path' on line x

I know that:

- There is no error with my mysqli connection as the rest of my application uses the credentials etc. fine to retrieve data from my db in both dev/live
- That this code runs fine, inserts correctly, doesn't error in my dev environment.

I've looked for solutions to the Error message- and have tried a few, but I remain unconvinced that this is the actual cause for the issue.

Comment: Wierd the code works on your dev machine... but you need to use '$mysqli->error' instead

Comment: I think it's because of the `else` in your code where you try to concatenate the mysqli object into the error message. Try removing that part and see if it works

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've discovered that one of the PHP variables I am passing into the INSERT statement seems to be the cause (the actual statement has about 9 variables, not just the 2 shown). I'm having trouble discerning the exact reason however as that is still fine in dev...

Answer (score 0):

PHP try to cast $mysqli to string here:

```
echo "Error: " . $mysqli . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
```

You should do that like this instead

```
echo "Error: with mysqli <br>" . $mysqli->error;
```

Or maybe a var vump if you want more details but mysqli->error should be enough

Comment: Why on the Earth one would want to echo $mysqli->error in **production** nevironment

Comment: Sure it's a bad idea but it's not the question here :p

Comment: I answer the question, if people want to output error in production it's not my problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @YourCommonSense I'm echoing the error to a javascript console log, I'm guessing this still isn't good practice?

Comment: In practice if you output error in production it's not safe, hackers can find security breach easier

Comment: Ah okay thanks for letting me know!